# How can I refer to an attached image in an email built with Email::Stuffer?

Tags: perl, email, mime

I want to send an email with `Email::Stuffer` and refer to an attached image in the html part of the email. For that I'd need the MIME part with the image to have an ID, but I cannot get `Email::Stuffer` to add one.

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Stuffer;

my $stuffer = Email::Stuffer
    ->from('me@example.org')
    ->to('you@example.org')
    ->subject('mcve')
    ->text_body('see attached image')
    ->attach_file('image.png');
print $stuffer->as_string(), "\n\n";

my @parts = $stuffer->email->subparts;
my $attachment = $parts[1];
my %headers = $attachment->header_str_pairs();
print "CID header: ", $headers{'Content-ID'}, "\n\n";
```

Oddly enough this prints something that looks like a content id, even though the mime structure it prints does not have the `Content-ID` header:

```
Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 10:33:05 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: me@example.org
To: you@example.org
Subject: mcve
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=16985071850.4fFe46cEc.181699


--16985071850.4fFe46cEc.181699
Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 10:33:05 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

see attached image=

--16985071850.4fFe46cEc.181699
Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 10:33:05 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: image/png; name=image.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=image.png

(some base64 data here)

--16985071850.4fFe46cEc.181699--


CID header: <16985071854.8a407.181699@perle>
```

It doesn't make a difference if I print after querying the content id header, so asking for one doesn't magically add it.

When I use `attach_file('image.png', 'Content-ID' => 'my@id');` instead of plain `attach`, it adds a `content-id` attribute to the `content-type` header like this: `Content-Type: image/png; content-id=my@id; name=image.png`.

I've tried to manually add a header to the image part

```
$headers{'Content-ID'} = $cid;
$attachment->header_str_set('Content-ID' => [$cid]);
```

but when I print the email as text, the `Content-ID` header still does not show up.

How can I get `Email::Stuffer` to add the `Content-ID` header to the image part?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer), Email::Stuffer should use `sendmail` by default. Are you able to do this successfully with `sendmail` only? Here is an example: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/222753-sendmail-header-footer-logo-html-body-2.html

Comment: @HåkonHægland I thought sendmail was only a means to deliver the email, independent of building it? I can send the email ok (specifying a `Transport`) but the image shows up as an attachment, not "embedded" in the html part. There is no `Content-ID` header on the image MIME part, hence the link doesn't work. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Have you tried using `Email::MIME` to add the Content-ID explicitly using `header_str` as shown in this section of the documentation: https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer#Why-use-this?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I've tried setting attributes (see edited post), but I wanted to avoid building the MIME structure manually... this was the whole point of using `Email::Stuffer`. Seems odd that such a basic feature would not work out of the box; I feel I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get Email::Stuffer to add the Content-ID header to the image part?

I did some debugging and the following modification of your script seems to work:

- Instead of using `$stuffer->email->subparts`, use `$stuffer->parts`
- Instead of using `$attachment->header_str_set('Content-ID' => [$cid]);`, use `$attachment->header_set('Content-ID', $cid);`

**Example**:

```
# ... Previous part of script as before...
my @parts = $stuffer->parts;
my $attachment = $parts[1];
$attachment->header_set('Content-ID', "<image.png>");
print $stuffer->as_string(), "\n\n";
```

**Output**:

```
[...]
Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 23:29:04 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: image/png; name=image.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=image.png
Content-ID: <image.png>

[...]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It's weird that I can get the id as in my code, and then have to stuff it back in like this, but if it works, it works!